# Vue - plot fixed points on an image that shrinks/grows

Tags: vue.js, plot, position, css-position

I am trying to make the numbers in this image hoverable, so on `mouseenter` on each yellow circled number, a card with some info appears, as shown.

All of the numbers (except for "1") are embedded in the image. I have made "1" absolute, with % values on bottom and left, so as the image shrinks and grows (responsive to screen width), the "1" loses it's position slightly.

Are there any more ways to do this which are much more accurate? Thanks!

[image]